# Pandas exporting variable dicts to csv has empty lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In the example code below, every second row in the .csv file that is created and appended to is empty. This is not intended, and I don't know how to stop it from happening. Is there a way to suppress this behaviour and output the data onto each row?

example:

```
import pandas as pd

for i in range(10):
    d = pd.DataFrame({'a':i+1*10, 'b':(i+1)**2}, index=[0])
    # Save in csv
    with open('some_dict.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        d.to_csv(f, header=f.tell()==0, index=False)
```

Comment: Hi, nice code with the ftell()-trick! If I run it on my machin though, it doesn't insert empty lines. Are you running it on linux or mac? is it possible that it somehow gets the line separator wrong? have you tried `open(..., mode='at', newline='\n')` already?

Comment: Thanks! strange, I'm just on Windows. But actually the `newline='\n'` argument fixed it, thanks for the suggestion! If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: Ok, thanks, I created an answer. I guess you also changed from `mode='a'` to `mode='at'`, right? Could you check again please, if you can omit the `newline` option? (now I'm curious).

Comment: Actually it seems to be the other way around - it is the `newline='\n'` that mattered. Changing `mode=a` to `mode=at` didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pandas somehow gets the line separator wrong, or maybe, because you didn't open the file as a text file.
I would try to open the file with the following options:

```
open(..., mode='at', newline='\n')
```